# How do I include LaTeX characters in R code?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I am trying to label some axes of a ggplot I have made in R Markdown, and I would like to include **(using LaTeX syntax)** the symbol for Theta in the label.

I have tried putting it inside dollar signs, which works in Markdown sections, but not in code blocks. I have attempted to use the same technique to get LaTeX characters in xlabel row, but get this error message:

! '\T' is an unrecognized escape in character string (:5:23)

```
Plot <- ggplot(df) + 
              geom_line(aes(x=theta,y=density))+
              ylab("Density")+
              xlab("$\Theta$ (Kg/ha)")
```

How can I specifically implement LaTeX expressions into my R code blocks? I have seen this can be done using unicode characters, **but I would like to use LaTeX expressions**, as unicode is not recognised by LaTeX when compiling a pdf with R Markdown.

For example in Python, we could write:

```py
plt.xlabel(r'\theta, (Kg/ha)')
```

To get the desired output.

Comment: R treats `\` as an escape character.  So you need to escape it to retain its literal meaning.  Try `xlab("$\\Theta$ (Kg/ha)")`

Comment: `xlab("$\\Theta$ (Kg/ha)")` did not work I'm afraid. Error:
! object 'xlab("$\\Theta$ (Kg/ha)")' not found